# DelegatingHandler in web api

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have custom implementation of DelegatingHandler in web api pipeline which does OAuth authentication.

At the moment, I have MVC web application (normal web controller) and those controllers would like to get data from web api controllers. Both of them is under same MVC web app project.

Which approaches should I take below ?

1. treat normal web controller as 'httpclient' to have proper web api request.

   cons: I feel it's a bit awkward (by specifing complete url for designated web api controller) as they are under same web project and it goes to complete IIS web request process.
2. Inside normal MVC web controller action, instantiate web api controller like normal .NET class..

   cons: I lose web authentication pipeline process on web api.

Thanks

Johana

Answer (score 0):

You could host the web API in-memory..

http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/asp-net-web-api-in-memory-hosting/

Comment: the map route definition is already been declared in global.asax. Is there any way I don't need to declare the line of code again?

Comment: Is httpclient one of REST clients? How about using RestSharp instead of httpclient?